# pthread_join returns a NULL address

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm new to thread programming in C. I have tried out a simple program below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* func(void* arg){
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n tid : %u \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self());
        return NULL;
}

int main(){
        pthread_t tid;
        void* ret;
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&func,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid,&ret);
        printf("\n ret status : %s \n",(char *)ret);
        return 0;
}
```

The ret status prints as NULL . Why does it print a NULL address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your functions returns `NULL`.

In other words, it will return whatever your function returns.

Check this example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* func(void* arg){
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n tid : %u \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self());
        return "I am done"; // I changed the return line
}

int main(){
        pthread_t tid;
        void* ret;
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&func,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid,&ret);
        printf("\n ret status : %s \n",(char *)ret);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
samaras@samaras-A15:~$ ./px

 tid : 3075947328 

 ret status : I am done <-- and not NULL
```

---

You should read the [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html).

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join() call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to pthread_exit() by the terminating thread shall be made available in the location referenced by value_ptr. When a pthread_join() returns successfully, the target thread has been terminated.

I also suggest yo read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513894/pthread-join-and-pthread-exit) question and check [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/#more-10260) link, which actually shows how you can use this functionality.

PS - I gave you a +1 for balance, but next time search harder before asking please. :)

Comment: Thanks Samras. I couldnt understand when I read the manual. But I could understand clearly after reading your answer. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

> The ret status prints as NULL . Why does it print a NULL address.

That happens because your thread function is returning `NULL`:

```
    return NULL;
```

If you change it to something like

```
    return "Hello, multithreaded world!";
```

you'll see the string getting printed out by the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to call `pthread_exit()`:

```
void* func(void* arg){
        sleep(1);
        printf("\n tid : %u \n",(unsigned int)pthread_self());
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Furthermore, if you return `NULL`, then this is what the return value will be.