# Questions about the pthread_join function

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* thread_function(void *ignoredInThisExample)
{
    char *a = malloc(20);
    strcpy(a,"hello world");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    char *b;

    pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL,&thread_function, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread_id,(void**)&b); //here we are reciving one pointer
                                        //value so to use that we need double pointer
    printf("b is %s.\n",b);

    return 0;
}
```

using `-O0` and `-O1` to compile and run:

```
[root c++]#gcc -g -O0 -o pthread pthread.c -lpthread
[root c++]#
[root c++]#
[root c++]#./pthread
b is hello world.
[root c++]#
[root c++]#
[root c++]#gcc -g -O1 -o pthread pthread.c -lpthread
[root c++]#
[root c++]#./pthread
b is .
```

why does this happen? source code from [pthread_join() and pthread_exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515532/10940200)
Since I am not familiar with assembly language, can anyone help me to analyze the reason ? [online assembly](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: You don't have a return statement in your `thread_function` resulting in undefined behavior.  Does this still happen if you `return a;`

Comment: as an aside, why are you running gcc and your compiled binary as root?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks ,but I found nothing in man pthread_exit(),by the way this is just a virtual machine running on the LAN, so don’t mind.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't return anything inside your `thread_function` is an UB, with `-O0` the compiler automatically solving this problem.  In fact, your function is:

```
thread_function:
      push    rbp
      mov     rbp, rsp
      sub     rsp, 32
      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
      mov     edi, 20
      call    malloc
      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
      mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
      movabs  rdx, 8031924123371070824
      mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
      mov     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 6581362
      nop
      leave
      ret
```

However, when you compile with `-O1`, your function is:

```
thread_function:
        ret
```

Also, if you don't know Assembly, you can understand that this procedure just returns without doing anything but if you add `return a;` at the end of your `thread_function`, your function becomes:

```
thread_function:
      sub     rsp, 8
      mov     edi, 20
      call    malloc
      movabs  rdx, 8031924123371070824
      mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
      mov     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 6581362
      add     rsp, 8
      ret
```

Now if you execute the program, the output is correct.

Comment: What does UB mean?

Comment: undefined behavior